# Loop takes too long to replace values

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

I have a 9 mln line of code where I have to replace every " . " with the number in the line above. Meaning that if column 1 contains " 7 ", the dot below should be replaced by that. But if column 3 contains " 44 ", the subsequent values have to be replaced by 44 and so on.

Problem: at the the moment it takes 18 minutes for 10,000 rows.

Have you any ideas how to optimize it? If yes, can you provide me the code please?

Tried to put values into another df and work from there, but it makes the things just slightly quicker (from 18 minutes to 17 min)

I don't know why but .replace did not work

```
for x in range(0,len(BD)):
    if BD['A_SECOND'].iloc[x] <> "." :
        Second = BD['A_SECOND'].iloc[x]
    else:
        BD['A_SECOND'].iloc[x] = Second
```

As said, the code should transform the first column into the second:

```
column1old    column1new
7             7
.             7
.             7
33            33
.             33
.             33
.             33
2             2
.             2
```

And so on..

THANKS! :)

Comment: Just for clarity, this "9 mln line of code" is in a data frame? What do you want to do with it afterwards? Write it out to a file? If so, you can change the "." as you write, keeping track of the number to use. Do some sums with it? Could you wrap it in a generator to yield changes as you go?

Comment: Hi Doctorlove, I do not have to do anything with the values, just replace it. What I did (and sorry if I did not write it immediately) to make the loop run and everytime it found a value <> "." to replace it with the last value which was not a "." And yes, these are in dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just replace the dots with NaN value and then use `fillna(method='ffill')`:

```
BD['A_SECOND'] = np.where(BD['A_SECOND'] == '.', np.nan, BD['A_SECOND'])
BD['A_SECOND'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following method took about 0.007 seconds for me on a dataframe of 10,000 rows:

```
import pandas as pd
from timeit import default_timer as timer

df = pd.DataFrame({"column1old": ["7", ".", ".", "33", ".", ".", ".", "2", ".", "."]})
for i in range(10):
    df = pd.concat((df, df), axis=0)  # gets a df of about 10,000 rows for speed comparison


def custom_replace(df, old_column):
    last_value = ""

    def insert_value(x):
        nonlocal last_value
        if x == ".":
            return last_value
        else:
            last_value = x
            return x

    return df[old_column].apply(insert_value)


start = timer()
df["column1new"] = custom_replace(df, old_column="column1old")
end = timer()
print(end - start)  # time elapsed in seconds
```

Comment: The use of `globals()['last_value']` is a lot less readable than just putting `global last_value` at the start of the function. Using a global is slower than a function local (Python has optimizations for those), so wrap the whole in a function and use `nonlocal` to access the variable in the outer function. And `lambda x: custom_replace(x)` is just a complicated way to write `custom_replace`, it's already a function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions! This lead to another speedup of about 2x